# Getting "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." Error while posting a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, viewmodel

I have a view model called StaffPerformanceVM where I Inject IPLLDetailService service using Unity Dependency Injector. Everything seems working until I post the AddNew Staff Performance form using this view model. I am getting the error at the end. I am new in Dependency Injection so I cannot figure it out how can I solve this?

Here is the Constructor of my View Model

```
    IPLLDetailService pLLDetailService;

    public StaffPerformanceVM(IPLLDetailService pLLDetailService)
    {
        this.pLLDetailService = pLLDetailService;
    }
```

Here is me Unity Bootstrapper class.

```
   private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), new InjectionConstructor(new DbContext("PLLEntities")));

        container.RegisterType<IErrorEngine, ErrorEngine>();
        container.RegisterType<ILoggingEngine, LoggingEngine>();
        container.RegisterType<IIdentityManager, IdentityManager>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmailNotificationEngine, EmailNotificationEngine>();

        container.RegisterType<ILogService, LogService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IPLLDetailService, PLLDetailService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IObjectiveService, ObjectiveService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICheckInService, CheckInService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IPersonService, PersonService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<StaffPerformanceVM>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        return container;
    }
```

This is the error I am encountering

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---------Stack Trace-----------------

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +247
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'PerformanceLearningLog.ViewModels.StaffPerformanceVM'.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +530
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +338
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Here is the Controller Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddPLLDetails(StaffPerformanceVM model)
    {
        String user = GetEmpNo();

        try
        {
            if (user != "")
            {
                LogCall(user, "PLL StaffPerformanceLog/AddPLLDetails-Post Page");
                model.StartDate = new DateTime(model.StartDateYear, model.StartDateMonth, model.StartDateDay);
                model.EndDate = new DateTime(model.EndDateYear, model.EndDateMonth, model.EndDateDay);
                model.AddPLLDetail(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorEngine.LogError(ex, "StaffPerformanceLog - AddPLLDetails-Post page not returning", user);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the controller code where you use the view model

Comment: Is there a reason to Inject a Service class to your ViewModel ? I normally inject a **service class** to my controller and the ViewModel only contains the properties I want to get and set the values.

Comment: Um, that's true. Just wanted to clean my controller

Answer (score -2):

The Compiler will provide a automatic Paramterless constructor if and only if there is no other Constructor given. Once you define a Parametised constructor, you have to provide the parameterless one manually.

It is complaning about there being none.